# Sphinx search: wordforms result

Tags: sphinx

There is a table with products.

`select * from mytbl where match('Rennie ');`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rennie with menthol flavor tablet 24 |
| 2 | Rennie Sugar Free tablet 24 |
| 3 | Rennie with orange tablet 24 |

My wordforms is:

`heartburn > rennie`

call keywords('rennie', 'mytbl');
+------+--------------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized    | normalized |
+------+--------------+------------+
| 1    | heartburn    | rennie     |
+------+--------------+------------+

But match returns empty set:
select * from mytbl where match('heartburn ');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

When I changed wordforms to:

`heartburn > rennie sugar`

query correctly find 1 row.

I need the keyword 'heartburn' was mapped to every string with 'rennie'.

Comment: I found a solution: ```heartburn > ren``` works correctly and return all of 3 rows. But why ```heartburn > rennie``` doesn't?

Comment: I would guess you have `morphology` also enabled on the index. So in the original document `Rennie` was transformed to `Ren`. When using morphology the left side needs to be 'morphed'. WHich is what you doing when using 'heartburn > ren'